# mmap a device and access it device's memory map

Tags: c, linux

I'm working on a very simple application which will test a device. There is no need for a driver and I have admin permissions.

I was going to use a `mmap` and this is where I got a confused.

The idea is to do the following

```
int devD = open("/path/to/my/device", "rw");
void *myDevPtr = mmap(start, length, prot, flags, devD, offset);
```

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/mmap.htm) is where I found the documentation for it. I'm confused about every parameter except the file descriptor and the protection.

`void *start`. What exactly this is the start of? Is it the start of memory map for my device?

`size_t length`. My device has its own memory map. Is it the length of my devices memory map or this is something else?

`int flags`. This one puzzles me. If my file descriptor is a device, what do I set my flags to?

`off_t offset`. This one is also confusing. This is an offset from the start pointer, but what exactly is this offset into?

Another is question that I have is about communicating with the mmapped device. Say I need to write data to a specific register in the device. How would I do it?

I realize that these questions might look too simplistic, but I've been at it for some time now and couldn't find a concrete example that would address my situation.

Any help with this is really appreciated.

Comment: `open(2)` returns an int

Comment: @self Not only that, it should be `int fd = open( "/path/to/dev", O_RDWR );`  [The manual](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html), for reading.

Comment: @self Thanks for pointing this out. I don't know how I missed it.

Comment: Relatively few devices implements mmap in their kernel file_operations table.  It makes sense for some video cards and for zero copy of a couple of network cards (but there are better ways of zero copy on a network card).    Does your device support mmap()? Does it really mmap the control registers instead of providing ioctl operations?

Comment: @evaitl Check out [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316121/mmap-a-device-and-access-it-devices-memory-map?noredirect=1#comment64050889_38316336)

Comment: *there is no need for a driver* -- the fact that you are opening a device file almost certainly means you are using a driver, especially if the path starts "/dev/..."

Answer (score 2):

> void *start. What exactly this is the start of? Is it the start of memory map for my device?

It's the logical address within your program where you want the mapping to occur. If you give it NULL, it will assign one [recommmended]. This is a "hint" and the address of the mapped area is the `mmap` return value

> size_t length. My device has its own memory map. Is it the length of my devices memory map or this is something else?

[Not knowing your device], I would assume it's the same. But, say your device was 6GB long. You may want to access this in sections, so you might specify (e.g.) 1MB instead. And, then, remap later [see the offset section]

> int flags. This one puzzles me. If my file descriptor is a device, what do I set my flags to?

Use `MAP_SHARED` so that what you write to the area is flushed to the "backing store" (which is your device).

> off_t offset. This one is also confusing. This is an offset from the start pointer, but what exactly is this offset into?

No, it is *not* an offset from `start`. It is the offset within your device that the mapping should be done to (i.e. just like the offset for `lseek`).

---

**UPDATE:**

> When you say: [Not knowing your device], I would assume it's the same. Do you mean that length is the length of the devices memory map?

From that standpoint, yes. *If* you want to map the *entire* area, which as I mentioned, can be large.

Normally, you map the entire device/file, starting at offset 0 for the length of the device/file.

> I'm also a little confused about the offset. Say my device has a register at offset 0x100. In order to read/write this register I would need to set offset to 0x100. Am I correct?

Yes and no. You can do it two ways. Herein, let's call the mapped address [the return value from `mmap`] by the name `mapbase`.

(1) Give `mmap` an offset parameter of 0x100. Then, do (e.g.) `val = *mapbase`. Effectively, this is saying to the OS: "I only care about this *one* register and you handle the mapping to it"

(2) Give `mmap` an offset parameter of 0. Then, do `val = mapbase[0x100]` Effectively, this is saying: "I want a mapping to *all* the registers and I will handle the indexing/offsetting manually"

Method (2) is more usual (i.e. you want to create a single mapping that can access just about any register). If you use method (1), what about a register that is located at 0x80? It's inaccessible [unless you do a remap, which is time consuming].

---

**UPDATE #2:**

As arsv pointed out, you may need to open `/dev/mem` to map to a device's registers.

This depends upon your device's *driver*. Suppose we have `/dev/mydevice`. Now, suppose we do `fdd = open("/dev/mydevice",O_RDWR)`

It is up to the driver to provide a mapping between I/O done to the open file descriptor (`fdd`) and the device's *registers*.

Some drivers support this, but most don't. If the device *does* support this, then we do the `mmap` with `fdd`

If it doesn't we have to do `fdm = open("/dev/mem",O_RDWR)` and pass `fdm` to `mmap`. Of course, now the `mmap` offset parameter will be radically different.

Comment: When you say: [Not knowing your device], I would assume it's the same. Do you mean that `length` is the length of the devices memory map? I'm also a little confused about the `offset`. Say my device has a register at offset 0x100. In order to read/write this register I would need to set `offset` to 0x100. Am I correct?

Comment: Another `offset` question. Say my device has a 1MB memory map. If I specify and offset 0 and a length of 1MB, does it mean I will be able to talk to every register in the device or in order to talk to a specific register I have to specify a specific offset? In other words in order to read/write 10 registers I will have to `mmap` 10 times with each `mmap` having its own offset

Comment: At the moment there is no driver for the device. In fact the ideas is to use some simple method to communicate with a device in order to give a team time to develop a driver and give something to hardware guys to test their hardware. It looks like I won't be able to use `open/close` for my device. It is possible to achieve the same thing by reading/writing to `/dev/mem`?

Comment: You could try [/dev/kmem and /dev/port](http://linux.die.net/man/4/kmem). Sooner or later though you will want the device to generate interrupts. Can't handle those in user space.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Mapping a physical device to a pointer in User space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827948/mapping-a-physical-device-to-a-pointer-in-user-space).

`start` is virtual memory address to map the device to. Leave NULL there.
`flags` should be MAP_SHARED.
`offset` is into the file being mmaped; for /dev/mem, that would be page-aligned physical address of the device.

Then just write to the mmaped area.

```
char* ptr = mmap(..., [/dev/mem], BASE);
*(ptr + OFFSET) = value;
```

Keep in mind that the physical address in this case will be (BASE + OFFSET).

Comment: In the link that you gave, the user does the following, memfd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC); Why open up /dev/mem instead of actually opening up a device in /dev?